# When using Symantec security, is our IP address our own or shared, should we whitelist?

Tags: network, network-access-control, whitelist

The company I work for uses Symantec security. When I am connected to the network (by cable) I can see that my IP address is registered to Symantec.

My question is, do other companies that are also using Symantec get this same address? I understand that this is more of a question for Symantec support, but I expect to get a quicker and more reliable answer here.

The reason I want to know is that the company that hosts our data-warehouse needs to white-list the IP address we will use to connect to the data warehouse. But if that address (those addresses, as it is probably a list) are also used by (all?) other Symantec customers than maybe we should connect only while on the 'guest'-network (which has a shorter, and presumably private IP-range).

Comment: Are you referring to your IP or the server IP from Symantec? Your first para refers to your IP and later you refer Symantec IP.

Comment: Its the same. If we connect to the outside world including the data warehouse through the Symantec proxy, then our our IP address == Symantec IP address.

Comment: Really, your question is "how does a specific product work?" and not a question about security.  Ask Symantec, but most likely they are sharing IPs across a variety of customers.

Comment: @David not really, because if Symantec does not gaurantee the IP-adresses are ours alone but in reality no one else is using them, them it probably is safe to whitelist. Also have there been any data-breaches because of whitelisten too many IP_adresses?